# Is possible to convert array in range?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to draw a chart but I can't convert array in range :

```
function extrair() {
    var dataSourceUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var ergonomia = dataSourceUrl.getRange(3,2,4,1).getValues();//B3:B6
    var chartBuilder = dataSourceUrl.newChart()
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
        .addRange(ergonomia)
        .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you first get the range and only then you get the array, you don't need to do that conversion. Just be sure to store the range first, introducing a variable:

```
function extrair() {
    var dataSourceUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var ergonomiaRange = dataSourceUrl.getRange(3,2,4,1); //B3:B6
    var ergonomia = ergonomiaRange.getValues(); //the array (which is not used in this code)
    var chartBuilder = dataSourceUrl.newChart()
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
        .addRange(ergonomiaRange)
        .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
        .build();
}
```